# dfs and bfs should be synonyms for depth-first-search and breadth-first-search (respectively)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When I was a mod, I spent a huge amount of time organising and cleaning up the site, but there are still things that can be improved (I wish someone else also cared about these things too - I would have more free time...).

As written in the title,

- [dfs](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dfs) should be made a synonym for [depth-first-search](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search)
- [bfs](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bfs) should be made a synonym for [breadth-first-search](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search)

Why? Because DFS and BFS are common acronyms for depth-first search and breadth-first search, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds good, I just suggested (and approved) them. Non-mods should still be able to suggest and vote on suggestions for synonyms by the way! But I guess only mods can circumvent the votes and just approve them right away, which does make things faster..

Comment: Suggesting synonyms and voting also requires a certain score in answers in that tag, which not a lot of people will meet.